# C# Access child members of hierarchy class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How do I access internal members of a class hierarchy? Below there is shopping cart, cartline. I want to access shoppingcart.Product (and compiler is not seeing this). Trying to make foreach to work also, I just need an optimal way, if anything else including typed property is better option, please let me know.

```
public class ShoppingCart : List<CartLine>
{
    public ShoppingCart()
    {

    }
}

public class CartLine
{
    public int CartLineId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

ShoppingCart shoppingcart = new ShoppingCart();
```

**This does not show up in Intellisense**

```
shoppingcart.Product
```

**Additionally, I would like to make foreach to work**

```
@model ShoppingCart

<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CartLineId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.ProductId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.ProductName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
```

Comment: From what you have posted, `Product` is a member of `CartLine` not `ShoppingCart`

Comment: So you may want to add a property to your cart that has the type list<cartLine> instead of inheriting from it. This will let you access products like so shoppingCart.CartLines[n].Product

Comment: Try  `shoppingcart[0].Product`... `ShoppingCart` is a a `List<CartLine>` so you have to access one of the items in that list to reference a `CartLine` object

Comment: trying to make foreach to work also, I just need an optimal way, if anything else including typed property is better option, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Product` is a property of `CartLine`, not `ShoppingCart`. In order to get access to that property, your `shoppingcart` variable would need at least one or more `CartLine` objects which could be accessed via the indexer property, and you'd be accessing that particular object instead:

```
var shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();
shoppingCart[0] = new CartLine { CartLineId = 100, Product = GetTestProduct(), Quantity = 1 };

Console.WriteLine(shoppingCart[0].Product.ToString());
```

Alternatively since `ShoppingCart` is intended as a model type, it might be better to not have it based on `List<T>`. Instead, try something like this:

```
class ShoppingCart
{
    public IList<CartLine> Items { get; } = new List<CartLine>();

    public ShoppingCart() {}
}
```

In this case, you'd access the first item's product like this:

```
shoppingCart.Items[0].Product
```

Comment: Thanks, what would be my new definition for Shopping cart, still the same? public class ShoppingCart : List<CartLine>
{
    public ShoppingCart()
    {

    }
}

Comment: @TVLamp: Yes, `ShoppingCart` would be the same as it is now. However, you might still be better served making `ShoppingCart` into a regular object with a `List<CartLine>` typed property, especially if you need to load/save carts from a database, JSON, etc. But that's a different story from this.

Comment: posted another question here, thanks, getting closer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52798897/c-sharp-access-child-members-of-hierarchy-with-foreach