# C# Access child members of hierarchy with foreach

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I am trying to make Foreach work for the html razor below. At the end of the day, I want ShoppingCart to be a list of CartLines. I want to get rid of the [0] statement, and make it variable. Any solution or optimal method would help. Feel free to edit the class also.

```
class ShoppingCart
{
    public IList<CartLine> Items { get; } = new List<CartLine>();

    public ShoppingCart() {}
}

public class CartLine
{
    public int CartLineId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

@model IEnumerable<ShoppingCart>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Items[0].Product)
        </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over your list elements, not your class:

```
class ShoppingCart
{
    public IList<CartLine> Items { get; } = new List<CartLine>();

    public ShoppingCart() {}
}

public class CartLine
{
    public int CartLineId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

@model ShoppingCart
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
   <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product)
        </td>
```

Answer (score 2):

so you are going to need a nested foreach:

```
@foreach (var cart in Model)
{    
    @foreach (var line in cart.Items )
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => line.Product) 
    }
}
```

Comment: abbreviated to just show the loops obliviously you build your html inside this

Comment: there has to be an easier way for this, I am just trying to create a synonym for (List of Cartlines) = ShoppingCart, now I have to conduct a double foreach, hopefully there is a C# library function which creates synonym

Comment: couldn't I do something like this? using ShoppingCart =IEnumerable<ElectronicsStore.Models.CartLine>;