# C# Declaring Type Definition Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I created a class Cartline. Then I created a collection called ShoppingCart.
When I try to declare ShoppingCart, I receive error. Does anyone know to fix this?

```
public class CartLine
{
    public int CartLineId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}


using ShoppingCart = System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ElectronicsStore.Models.CartLine>;

ShoppingCart shoppingcart = new ShoppingCart();

Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'IEnumerable<CartLine>'    ElectronicsStore
```

Comment: ShoppingCart is set to IEnumerable<Cartline>, which is an interface - you cannot instanciate an interface..  Change it to List<CartLine>

Comment: Thanks, why not ShoppingCart shoppingcart = new IEnumerable<CartLine>(); , instead of List?

Comment: @StevenMayer explained why. `IEnumerable<T>` is an interface. You can't create instances of interfaces, only concrete classes.

Comment: what I'm really trying to do is create a synonym for (List of Cartlines) = ShoppingCart,  how do I declare ShoppingCart, without ever referring to Cartlines except once? I want to declare Shopping cart many times throughout the program

Comment: also, want to be able to access the cartline members from shopping cart, including product, quantity,   and run foreach like this    @foreach (var line in shoppingcart.cartline )
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => line.Product) 
    }

Comment: Create a new class ShoppingCart that has a property of List<CartLine>. I'm guessing Cartline consists on PRoduct and Quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is self explanatory.  Two options - you can create an alias using a concrete type (e.g. `List<CartLine>`) but, instead, I'd recommend you define a class that inherits from `List<CartLine>` (or whatever collection best suits your needs):

```
public class ShoppingCart : List<CartLine>
{
    // implement constructors you want available
    public ShoppingCart(){}

    public ShoppingCart( IEnumerable<CartLine> collection ) : base( collection ) {}

    public ShoppingCart( int capacity ) : base( capacity ) {}

    // the benefit here is you can add useful properties
    // if CartLine had a price you could add a Total property, for example:
    public decimal Total => this.Sum( cl => cl.Quantity * cl.Price );
}
```

Then you may use as requested:

```
var cart = new ShoppingCart();
cart.Add( new CartLine() { ... } );
var cartTotal = cart.Total;
... etc ...
```

Collection initializer will also work:

```
var cart = new ShoppingCart() { new CartLine() { ... }, ... }
```

Or initialize with existing `IEnumerable<CartLine>`, e.g. an `IQueryable<CartLine>` using Entity Framework:

```
var cart = new ShoppingCart( dbContext.CartLines.Where( ... ) );
```

Comment: I noticed this solution only requires @foreach (var item in Model),  I will have to read up on base( collection)

Comment: Yes, `ShoppingCart` is an `IEnumerable<CartLine>` in this implementation.  The constructor that takes an `Enumerable<CartLine>` parameter allows for initializing the collection with an existing `IEnumerable<CartLine>`, so if you're loading `CartLine` enties w/ EF, for example, you can simply call `new ShoppingCart( dbContext.CartLines.Where( ... ) );`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to creating a new class called ShoppingCart that has a property which is a List of CartLine entities:

```
public class CartLine
{
    public int CartLineId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class ShoppingCart
{
    public IList<CartLine> CartLines {get;set;}
}


ShoppingCart shoppingcart = new ShoppingCart();
```

Comment: If you go with this solution, please understand that you'll need to instantiate the IList (an interface) to a concrete class such as List<CartLine>. This would look like IList<CartLine> cartLines = new List<CartLine>(); then you're able to CartLines.Add(cartline)

Comment: and when I do this, I have to conduct a double foreach, see here, I am trying to avoid double foreach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52798897/c-sharp-access-child-members-of-hierarchy-with-foreach

Comment: @StevenMayer Maybe it's better to instantiate it in ShoppingCart constructor

Comment: @AminMozhgani agreed, if you're going to be adding products via the shopping cart (which sounds about right). TVLamp, in my opinion, the model for that View should be a ShoppingCart, not an IEnumerable. Then you'll only have to foreach through the CartLines.  If it is possible for a user to have multiple shopping carts, can't help the double foreach then.

Comment: @TVLamp Why you have a List of ShoppingCarts in your view? What's the meaning of it?

Comment: if I do this, @model ShoppingCart,  it says, foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'ShoppingCart' because 'ShoppingCart' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator' ElectronicsStore

Comment: do a foreach (var cart in Model.CartLines) - this is the list to iterate on.  Or go with the above solution which makes ShoppingCart a list of CartLines already

Comment: You should iterate over the property, not the class.  `foreach(var CartLine in Model.CartLines)`